# can the google plus open ID requests be replaced with the standard google requests?

Tags: openid-connect, google-oauth, google-identity

I've been working on an application that has been previously using many open ID providers, including google signin and google profile.  As I understand it, the google profile APIs are being deprecated, and I need to transition off.  That being said, do both the google and the google profile signin methods result in the same openID? - i.e. were they interchangeable and could someone have logged in using one or the other and be logged into the same account in the end?

In essence, can I just remove the google profile signin method and have everyone still work or do I need some way to transition over users?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same Google account. If you just used the email as the identifier it will be identical. Just drop the plus scopes.